# How do I Highlight a DataGridViewComboBoxCell when it has focus?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, selection-color

I have a `DataGridView` with a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. When I navigate through any of the cells they get highlighted. My problem is when I navigate through the `ComboBoxColumn` cells they don't get highlighted. This is my code for creating the column.

```
        DataGridViewCellStyle GridStyleCombo = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        DataGridViewCell cell2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        {
            CellTemplate = cell2,
            Name = "boundProfile",
            HeaderText = "Promotion Bound Profile",
            DataPropertyName = "BoundProfile",
            DataSource = new BindingSource(DA.GetProfiles(), null),
            FillWeight = 10,
            AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill,
            SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic,
            DefaultCellStyle = GridStyleCombo,
            DisplayMember = "Key",
            ValueMember = "Value"
        };
```

Is there a way to somehow highlight those cells?I've already tried changing the selection color of the `DataGridViewCell` or the `DataGridViewCellStyle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I found that if I set the grid's `EditMode` property to `EditOnEnter`, the combobox cell was highlighted when I entered the cell.

It also solved the problem of having to click two or three times on the cell before the combobox drop down would appear.

The only problem with this solution is, that when the `EditMode` property is set to `EditOnEnter`, and you select a row by clicking on the row header, the entire row will be selected, but only one cell will be in edit mode. This causes the following: if you try to delete the row by selecting the row header, you cannot delete the row because the delete key is actually being sent to the cell being edited, not to the row.

Comment: I never really like working with `row headers` so that problem wasn't really an issue. Thanks a lot for the suggestion, just tested it and it works like a charm although i did solve it by doing this in the `datagrid cellclick event`


            if (dataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn && validRow)
            {
                dataGrid.BeginEdit(true);
                ((ComboBox)dataGrid.EditingControl).DroppedDown = true;
            }